# What's JavaCC's ADVANTAGE versus ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, javacc

Too many people have told me about the disadvantages, but what is its advantage if any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaCC doesn't require its own runtime JAR (the code it generates runs on its own), whereas ANTLR does.

Comment: Wait.  ANTLR generates Java, but that Java won't run on the same runtime as an existing Java application?  I'm a bit confused.  Does JavaCC let you directly execute its parsed structure rather than needing to go through compiling and dynamic class loading?

Comment: @ebyrob: The code generated by ANTLR requires the ANTLR JAR to be on the classpath when that code is executed, whereas the JavaCC-generated code will run on its own.

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC is incredibly easy to learn if you already know Java. The syntax is quite similar to standard Java syntax, and the differences are intuitive.

Comment: +1 This matches my experience with JavaCC a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC can generate C++ as of last year and Sreeni (the maintainer) is improving the system.

http://java.net/projects/javacc/lists/users/archive/2011-02/message/10